# Where does Joomla store article images?

Tags: image, joomla, directory, directory-structure

Where in the Joomla directory can I look to find images stored in articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default images uploaded are stored in the %root%/images directory, however, images may be stored in subdirectories of the images folder.  The native editor and Joomla Content Editor (JCE, a commonly used editor for Joomla!) will only allow you to insert images from the images folder and subfolders into articles.  It is possible to insert images from elsewhere in the %root% folder by directly editing the `img` tag in the article's code, but this is not best practice.

*If using FTP, %root% may be /public_HTML/.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple after searching all files in a joomla site..My customer used k2 articles at his old site, i have never used joomla before..So, all images are stored at k2/items/cache/filename.jpg, this filename.jpg is generated using md5("Image" . Post ID) . "_Extension.jpg", where Post ID is the int 1 for example and Extension is for the image size (Generic, XL, L, M etc). For k2 articles the library is located in components/mod_k2/helpers/item.php