# Joomla 1.7 where are image paths stored for articles?

Tags: database, joomla

I've been tasked to migrate a Joomla 1.7 site to Drupal, which is going fairly well, except that I can't find where Joomla stores image paths for articles in the database. In the jos_articles table I have the following columns:

id
title
subtitle
cat
atype
theme
topics
intro
description
geography
source
author
extraauthors
published
featured
created_date
publish_date
unpublish_date
modified_date
hits

Any ideas?

EDIT: figured it out - the template automatically looks for [article-id].jpg, which means they aren't stored in the database at all!!!

Nothing to see here folks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does joomla store article/ modules text and image path in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276397/does-joomla-store-article-modules-text-and-image-path-in-database)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla keeps information from the articles and pages that you create in two places. First of all, the text of the articles are keep as records in a database. All Joomla sites use a database to keep a lot of the information that helps manager the site, and your articles (and links, and contact items, etc.) are in that database. Generally, the database is provided by a database called mySQL that is provided as part of your web hosting service. Joomla manages getting articles in and out of this for you automatically.
So, you will not find a “file” on your website that contains the text of your articles. It is stored away in the Joomla mySQL database.
Now, photos, icons, graphics, and things like that are not stored in the database. They are actually stored as files in the file system of your Joomla installation.

Check this Article: 
http://welcometojoomla.com/how-do-i-articles/34-site-management/76-where-does-joomla-keep-the-articles

Answer (score 0):

By reading below article you will get the answer.

[Does joomla store article/ modules text and image path in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276397/does-joomla-store-article-modules-text-and-image-path-in-database)

[Where does Joomla store article images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739337/where-does-joomla-store-article-images)

[Where does Joomla keep the articles?](http://welcometojoomla.com/how-do-i-articles/34-site-management/76-where-does-joomla-keep-the-articles)

Comment: Nope not really - the article content is stored in the jos_article table, and there is no images column in that table. The jos_content table doesn't contain the articles, I don't know if this is normal or not as I don't usually use Joomla

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 1.7 the Article image urls are stored inside the `#__content` table

It was saving image url inside the `introtext` column with the article content. The images are from different location like `images/banners/` or from any folder that access from media manager.

Hope its helps.

Comment: I think the database I've been given must be set up differently to a normal install - they are definitely not in the content table. There are some 'standard pages' data in there, but not the articles, which seem to be a different content type with a separate table. Thanks for the help, I will keep looking.

Comment: Then someone may customize the article section also check any other extensions like K2 or something is used to manage articles